# Question on existence of trigonometric fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Real values $b, c, x, y, z$ are such that $x+y+z = \pi/3+b+c = \pi$

The problem is to find trigonometric function $F(x, y, z, b, c)$ such that

For $(x, y, z)\not= (0, 0, \pi), (0, \pi, 0), (\pi, 0, 0)$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{F(x, y, z, b,c)}{F(x, z, y, c, b)} &= \frac{\sin(x-z)}{\sin(x-y)}, && \text{if }b=c=\pi/3  \\[4pt]
\frac{F(x, y, z, b,c)}{F(x, z, y, c, b)} &= \frac{\cos(y-c)\cos(z-\pi/3)}{\cos(z-b)\cos(y-\pi/3)}, &&\text{if }x=0\\[4pt] 
\frac{F(x, y, z, b,c)}{F(x, z, y, c, b)} &= \frac{\cos(x+b+2\pi/3)}{\cos c}, &&\text{if }y=0\\[4pt] 
\frac{F(x, y, z, b,c)}{F(x, z, y, c, b)} &= \frac{\cos b}{\cos(x+c+2\pi/3)}, &&\text{if }z=0.
\end{align}$$

In general I am interested in trigonometric function $F(x, y, z, a, b, c)$ such that

For $x+y+z=a+b+c=\pi$ and $(x, y, z)\not= (0, 0, \pi), (0, \pi, 0), (\pi, 0, 0)$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{F(x, y, z, a, b,c)}{F(x, z, y, a, c, b)} &= \frac{\sin(x-z)}{\sin(x-y)}, && \text{if }a=b=c=\pi/3  \\[4pt]
\frac{F(x, y, z, a, b,c)}{F(x, z, y, a, c, b)} &= \frac{\cos(y-c)\cos(z-a)}{\cos(z-b)\cos(y-a)}, &&\text{if }x=0\\[4pt] 
\frac{F(x, y, z, a, b,c)}{F(x, z, y, a, c, b)} &= \frac{\cos(x+b+2a)}{4\cos^2 a\cos c}, &&\text{if }y=0\\[4pt] 
\frac{F(x, y, z, a, b,c)}{F(x, z, y, a, c, b)} &= \frac{4\cos^2 a\cos b}{\cos(x+c+2a)}, &&\text{if }z=0.
\end{align}$$

By trigonometric function $F(x, y, z, b, c)$ I mean function of the form $\prod_i\sin(\lambda_{i}x+\ldots+\mu_ic+\gamma_i)$ with constants $\lambda_i,\ldots,\gamma_i$.

Comment: Your question is missing some important features of a [good question for this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), in particular it is [missing a lot of context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). First, it is quite unclear what you mean by a "trigonometric function $F(x,y,z,b,c)$" for purposes of this question; can you provide a definition? What approaches to you already know for such questions? Are there simpler such questions which you can solve? If so, have you tried to adapt the solution?

Comment: If two conditions hold, the formulas don't match. For instance, if $b=c=\pi/3$ **and** $x=0$ (so that $z=\pi-y$), the first formula reduces to $1$ while the second does not. ... This question appears to be related to —or perhaps a refinement of— [your previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3724763/409). (As I recall, the first draft of that question had a similar inconsistency, although you corrected it.) It would help if you described the broader scenario from which this problem derives. This can provide a sense of the what kinds of functions might (and might not) work.

Comment: Your edit makes the first two formulas match for $b=c=\pi/3$ **and** $x=0$. But it also changed the last two formulas, which (still) don't match for $y=z=0$ (so that $x=\pi$). ... If you'll pardon my frankness: At this pt, I'm not sure I could ever *trust* your formulas, even once they manage to yield consistent values for obvious test cases; for all I know, a subtler error could be lurking. Unless/until you provide some info about the underlying problem —for sanity-checking those formulas, if nothing else— I'm afraid I'm disinclined to give your question(s) any consideration. ... Good luck!

Comment: I edited the question based on first Blue remark. I rechecked it should be correct. We cannot assume that both $y, z=0$. For example the formula $sin(x-y)/sin(x-z)$ for $x+y+z=\pi$ is equal to $1/(2\cos(x))$ if $y=0$ and to $2\cos(x)$ for $z=0$ and obviously $1/(2\cos(x))\not=2\cos(x)$ if $x=\pi$.

Comment: My motivation is following. For a triangle $ABC$ with angles $\pi/3, b, c$ and a point $P$ with angles $\angle BPC = \pi-x$, $\angle APC = \pi-y$, $\angle APB=\pi-z$ I have a function $G$ which has the values as in the question if $P$ lies on the sides of $ABC$. And I want to find trigonometric formula for $G$ in the form $F/F$. And obviously there doesn't exists $P$ with $(x, y, z)=(\pi, 0, 0)$ because in the limiting case $P\to A$ we have $x=2\pi/3$, $y+z = \pi/3$ and if $y=0$ then $P\in AC$ if $z=0$ then $P\in AB$.

Comment: You should include your motivation in the question-proper; comments are easily overlooked. Be that as it may ... The motivation seems to rule-out problematic cases, so that's good. (And that's why providing such context is important!) However, if $b=c=\pi/3$ and $y=0$, which appears a valid situation, the first formula reduces to $-2\cos x$ and the third to $2\cos x$. Similarly for $b=c=\pi/3$ and $z=0$. So, trust issues persist. :) ... I'd still like to know what exactly you're trying to  accomplish here; what does your $G$ function *do*? A holistic understanding of the geometry can only help

Comment: I edited the question. Geometry behind it is complicated and definitely will not help. I have a program which provide me with values of $G$ for each $ABC$ and $P$. Also there may be some absolute value mistakes because it uses absolute value for computing lengths and integrals.

Comment: So, you're saying the formulas still might not be correct (due to absolute value issues), but you won't provide the geometric context that could provide clarity. You should *definitely* include that disclaimer as part of the question-proper, so that readers know they're facing a potentially (and hopelessly?) ill-posed problem. I personally don't see much point in continuing, so I'll take my leave. Good luck to you! ("Extended discussion" warning. I won't be commenting further.)

Comment: I checked it is correct in absolute value and likely to be correct because all the equations are equal on the boundary. I am sorry for many mistakes in the question. Geometry behind it requires some terminology and theory of undergraduate level so I cannot post it as a comment and it is too lengthy and not very motivating for posting.

Comment: In the general case (with $a$ not-necessarily $\pi/3$) ... If $P$ *approaches* $A$ along side $AB$, then $z=0$, $y\to a$, $x\to\pi-a$ so that by the fourth formula, $G=4\cos^2a$. If $P$ approaches $A$ along $AC$, then $y=0$, $z\to a$, $x\to\pi-a$, so that by the third formula $G=1/(4\cos^2a)$. Consequently, if $\cos a\neq \pm1/2$, there's a discontinuity at $A$ (likewise at $B$ and $C$ under their own conditions). That's not the worst thing in the world, but I find myself compelled to ask: Is that actually your intention, or is it an indication that the problem is due for another revision? :)

Comment: I rechecked it many times and it is true in absolute value. I agree with You and it is not continuous in $A$. See also my comment several posts ago where I showed that $\sin(x-y)/sin(x-z)$ is a $F/F$ formula (in absolute value) for $1, \{x=0\}$ and $1/(2\cos(x)), \{y=0\}$ and $2\cos(x), \{z=0\}$. In the limit $y=0$, $x\to\pi-a$ and $z=0$, $y\to\pi-a$ $1/(2\cos(a))\not= 2\cos(a)$.

Comment: I noticed that if we divide every boundary conditions on $\frac{\sin(x-z)}{\sin(x-y)}\frac{\cos(y-c)\cos(z-a)}{\cos(z-b)\cos(y-a)}$ which is of the form $F/F$ then we reduce problem to finding function of the form $F/F$ with conditions $F/F=1$ if $a=b=c$ or $x=0$ and $\frac{\cos(x+b+2a)\cos(x+b)}{8\cos a\cos^2 c\cos(x+a)\cos x}$ if $y=0$ and $\frac{8\cos a\cos^2 b\cos(x+a)\cos x}{\cos(x+c+2a)\cos(x+c)}$ if $z=0$. I rechecked it on computer program and all the computations are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no such formula in variables $a, b, c, x, y, z$ but if we consider a triangle $ABC$ and point $P$ with $\angle BPC = \pi-x$, $\angle APC = \pi-y$, $\angle APB = \pi -z$ and add additional angles $A=\angle CAP$, $A'=\angle PAB$, $B=\angle ABP$, $B'=\angle PBC$, $C=\angle BCP$, $C'=\angle PCA$ then the formula

$$F/F=\\\frac{\sin(x-y)^2\cos(z-a) \sin z  \sin B'  \sin^4 c \cos b }{\sin(x-z)^2\cos(y-a) \sin y  \sin C  \sin^4 b \cos c}\times\\\times\frac{ \left(\frac{\tan A }{ \tan C'} - \frac{\tan A' }{\tan C }\right) \left(\frac{\tan A  }{ \tan C' } - \frac{\tan a }{\tan c }\right) \left(\frac{\tan A'  }{ \tan C } - \frac{\tan a  }{\tan c }\right)}{ \left(\frac{\tan A }{ \tan B' } - \frac{\tan A'  }{ \tan B }\right) \left(\frac{\tan A }{\tan B' }-\frac{\tan a  }{ \tan b }\right) \left( \frac{\tan A'  }{\tan B }-\frac{\tan a }{ \tan b }\right)}$$

is correct.

I found it by fixing triangle $ABC$ and looking at the zeroes and poles of boundary conditions as a functions on $P$ and guessing the trigonometric function with the same zeroes and poles. By complex analysis theorem about meromorphic function we can conclude that this function will be equal to our boundary conditions up to constant. Finally I guessed the constant value.